# How to sense if someone has clicked an area in android?

Tags: android, button

I am trying to create an activity that changes backgrounds once someone clicks (and holds) an image of a button in the middle of the screen. The app will switch back to its normal background once the button is released.

So far I've tried placing a button in front of the "area" to press and set its visibility to invisible.

Is there a better way to do this? Is there a way to sense if the person let go of the button? (e.g. on button pressed do some stuff, when button released do other stuff)

Thanks

Comment: you want to perform that action by keeping some view in the middle or a blank UI..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want something like [NumberPickerButton](http://www.google.com/codesearch#uX1GffpyOZk/core/java/android/widget/NumberPickerButton.java&type=cs) and [NumberPicker](http://www.google.com/codesearch#uX1GffpyOZk/core/java/android/widget/NumberPicker.java&q=android%20numberpicker.java&type=cs).

You should enable long clicking (setLongClickable(true))  on your button.
Then respond to both onLongClick event, and the onTouchEvent, if action is UP.

Your event handlers should look something like this:

```
public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
  changeYourBackground();
  return true;
}

public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
  if ((event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL)
        || (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP)) {
     putYourBackgroundBack();
  }
  return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}
```

Comment: Sounds about right, but I think he may just want to implement  only onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) and  do changeYourBackground() if it is MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN.  That would make the image change immediately rather than after the long click delay.

Comment: If he wants the picture to change on touch than ha has to do it the way you described.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using canvas.In that,you can just take an image to be displayed in middle of canvas and catch the touch event on area,the image covers.And when user touches that area,change the background color of canvas.

Comment: i think he needs something that changes when touched and reverts to original when unpressed. You can use the onTouch listener with the two events being ontouch and onrelease. Should work fine, don't know the exact android code.